# How can I Edit information including Video using laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, edit

I Have Written this code in controller...

```
public function updaterec(Request $req)
    {
        
        $subject=$req->subj;
        $coursename=$req->cname;
        $desc=$req->desc;
        if($req->hasfile('vdos'))
        {
            $file=$req->file('vdos');
            $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename=time().'.'.$extension;
            $file->move('2x/',$filename);
           
        }
        // $rec->save();
        // echo "updated";
        DB::update('update htmlvdo set subject=?,coursename=?,desc=?,video=? where vid=?',[$subject,$coursename,$desc,$filename,$req->id]);
        echo "updated";

    }
```

Comment: You need to give us a _way_ more detailed explanation of what you're asking here. What doesn't work? Where are you stuck? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered.

Comment: if i click on edit button then edit the information like username,email id, and also Edit uploaded video in laravel when update the form...

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70799721/edit) your question to include a proper description so people don't need to read through all comments just to know what the question is. Also make sure to read those links I posted because the info in your comment doesn't cover it.

Comment: fyi, there's no "standard" way for editing videos on a web page. There _might_ be JS packages out there  that do this, but you'd need to find them on your own